# Angular5: Error: macroTask 'requestAnimationFrame'

Tags: javascript, angular

Using `polyfills.js` and `video.js` after loading video, consoles this error :

> Error: macroTask 'requestAnimationFrame': can not transition to 'running', expecting state 'scheduled', was 'notScheduled'.

I am looking for a way to resolve this error, btw video is playing and and there is no other problem except showing this error.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `src/polyfills.ts` add this line

```
(window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true;
```

may need to re-run `ng serve` if running locally.

Note that if you're using requestAnimationFrame elsewhere or in an angular library such as angular/components it may cause change detection issues

Comment: I am long away that project but i am going to trust you :)